# Is it possible to pass html element width to stateless child component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a stateless container component and a stateless child table component. The table needs to know the width of the outer div of the parent component for use as a maxWidth. I'm having trouble passing this value down to the child.

Firstly I have the parent pass a callback method to its outermost rendering div as a ref to store the ref as a variable on the parent (the ref is on the div; I know stateless components can't have refs), but if I then try to pass ReactDOM.findDOMNode(parentVarContainingRefToDiv).offsetWidth to the child it complains that the child's render must be pure and not contain stale refs. The same thing happens if I pass a method from the parent that returns the width to the child.

I tried to make the parent stateful and save the width as a state to pass down, but I couldn't find a good lifecycle to do this in (WillUpdate endlessly renders if state is changed there). I considered doing a combo of WillUpdate and ShouldUpdate, but sounds icky if it even would work.

Another thing I considered was sending the child a method with which it sends back yet another method to the parent for storing the width value on the child. Also sounds icky.

The only thing that sounds plausible from where I'm standing is making the child be stateful and do something tricky within WillReceiveProps.

Is this the only way? I'd like to keep both components stateless if at all possible.

Sorry there's no code, I cycled through several different versions to come up with the scenarios above, but I can try to recreate them if a no-code question is unbearable.

Answer (score 0):

In Reactjs, if you need to use findDOMNode, you are not respecting the principle, the structure, of React. You should NEVE use it. Try looking for component online. [Like this one](https://github.com/digidem/react-dimensions) ;)

Getting a component from the DOM breaks the objective hierarchic structure of a React project.

Comment: That's not completely true. It is to be avoided in almost all cases, which is why people go around overstating it as "NEVER USE", but there are things that cannot be done without it, namely when actual DOM properties and methods are needed. How else would you focus() on an input? You have to retrieve the DOM object to call native DOM methods like that. 

But thank you for the component suggestion. I looked in the code and he is using resize events to suck in the DOM width information rather than with findDOMNode. I like that idea much better.